# Batch deletes using stackexchange.Redis?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Our application has to evict an array of keys (probably a few hundred) from Redis. Is there a way to batch delete in Stackexchange.Redis?

Answer (score 1):

The `IDatabase[Async]` interface has a `KeyDelete[Async]` method that accepts a `RedisKey[]` and returns the number of keys removed. Note that `RedisKey` is implicitly castable from `string` and `byte[]` representations of keys. This is implemented using the varadic form of the [`del`](http://redis.io/commands/del) command.